# Probability that workday bus ride exceeds weekend bus ride

Tags: statistics

Duration of a bus ride from my house to the office any day of the work-week follows normal distribution N(30,10). A bus ride during the weekend, same route, home-office, follows N(20,5). What is the probability that the duration of the bus ride on Tuesday exceeds the bus ride on Saturday?

We can say that a bus ride on any single day is an independent event and the distribution is the same during the day, Monday-Friday (we are not accounting for a rush hour or a bus delay), or Saturday-Sunday.

UPD: in N(30,10), 30 is the mean and 10 is the variance. Hope this clears the confusion.

Hope this makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: Wow, the weekday ride has about a $1$-in-$740$ chance of getting you there before you set out! :-) ¶ Hint: The weekday ride time minus the weekend ride time is also normally distributed.  What is its mean?  What is its standard deviation?  What is the probability that it is positive?

Comment: @BrianTung , I am sorry, I am not sure I understand your hint. Yes, the difference in travel times will be normally distributed as well. So, how this is helping me?

Comment: If you know it's normally distributed, with a known mean and standard deviation, then you will know when it's positive.  What does it mean when the difference in travel times is positive?

Comment: I know perfectly well what the answer is.  I've given you everything but the last step.

Comment: **Nobody** can know the answer for sure until you reveal whether 10 and 5 are populations variances or standard deviations. Notation differs from one author to the next.

Comment: @BruceET, it's variance! Let me update the question.

Comment: @BrianTung, I am looking for a number, probability that the weekday ride is longer than the same ride on the weekend. That's it. Do you know how to calculate it? If yes, can you please reply. I am sorry, I have no time for a guessing game. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You have to meet us halfway. What is the mean and variance of the difference between the two times? Calculate that and I’ll explain how to go the rest of the way. This isn’t a homework-answering service, and your impatience isn’t exactly convincing me to bend the purpose of the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will outline the *method.*

(1) On Tuesday your travel time $T$ is
normally distributed with mean $\mu_T = 30,$ variance
$\sigma_T^2 = 10,$ and standard deviation $\sigma_T = 3.162.$

(2) On Saturday your travel time $S$ is
normally distributed with mean $\mu_S = 20,$ variance
$\sigma_S^2 = 5,$ and standard deviation $\sigma_S = 2.236.$

(3) As @BrianTung hinted, the difference $D$ in travel times is normally distributed with mean $\mu_D = \mu_T - \mu_S = 30 - 20 = 10.$ You may have this fact in your text or notes as something like: $E(X \pm Y) = E(X) \pm E(Y).$

Because you say Tuesday and Saturday travel times are *independent,* the variance of the difference is
$\sigma_D^2 = \sigma_T^2 + \sigma_S^2 = 10 + 5 = 15.$

[Be careful here: Notice that independence in *required* and that the *variances are added* even though the random variables are subtracted. Also, notices that variances add, but standard deviations do not.]

Be sure to look in your text or notes for an equation that supports this adding of variances. My crystal ball says there is a 78.3% chance something like this will show up on an axam.

Thus $D$ is a normal random variable with $\mu_D = 10$ and $\sigma_D^2 = 15.$ I will leave it to you to use
standard methods to find $P(D > 0).$

---

Here is a histogram of a sample of a million hypothetical travel time distances $D = T - S.$
The density curve is for the normal distribution
derived above.

[image]

The R code for the simulation is shown below. 
Notice that R uses the standard deviation $\sigma$ as the second parameter.] Technically, `d > 0` is a
'logical' vector consisting of a million `TRUE`s & `FALSE`s, its `mean` is the proportion of its TRUEs.
With a million iterations, the approximation of
$P(D > 0)$ should be accurate to about three decimal
places.

```
set.seed(412)   # for reproducibility
m = 10^6
t = rnorm(m, 30, sqrt(10))
s = rnorm(m, 20, sqrt(5))
d = t - s
mean(d);  var(d)
[1] 9.99688     # aprx E(D) = 10
[1] 15.00828    # aprx Var(D) = 15
mean(d > 0);  mean(t > s)
[1] 0.995112    # aprx P(D > 0) = ??
[1] 0.995112    # another method for same
```

Comment: thank you, professor, it makes perfect sense. Yes, I understand and know about the sum of variances vs differences in means. It definitely helped when you spelled it out like this. My impatience and attempts to calculate everything in my head are not always working. Thank you!